# Coredata random crashes 1560, 1550

Tags: ios, core-data, objectmapper

Sometimes it's giving this

```
    2017-07-25 11:57:51.839 Test[14097:17556837] CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  -[__NSCFSet addObject:]: attempt to insert nil with userInfo (null)
2017-07-25 11:57:51.852 Test[14097:17556837] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFSet addObject:]: attempt to insert nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01573a94 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00c9be02 objc_exception_throw + 50
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x015739bd +[NSException raise:format:] + 141
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x01449d69 -[__NSCFSet addObject:] + 185
    4   CoreData                            0x010c8e00 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _processPendingInsertions:withDeletions:withUpdates:] + 560
    5   CoreData                            0x010c3a1c -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _processRecentChanges:] + 2204
    6   CoreData                            0x010c3166 -[NSManagedObjectContext processPendingChanges] + 54
    7   CoreData                            0x01096355 _performRunLoopAction + 357
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x0148d77e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x0148d6de __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 398
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x0148305c __CFRunLoopRun + 1340
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x01482866 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x0148267b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    13  GraphicsServices                    0x0801e664 GSEventRunModal + 192
    14  GraphicsServices                    0x0801e4a1 GSEventRun + 104
    15  UIKit                               0x01e5dcc1 UIApplicationMain + 160
    16  Test                                0x000f3a2b main + 75
    17  libdyld.dylib                       0x0496fa21 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Sometimes it's giving me this

```
fatal error: Failure to save context: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1550 “The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1550.)” UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1550.), Dangling reference to an invalid object.=null, NSValidationErrorObject=<Test.Article: 0x7c191030> (entity: Article; id: 0x7c1927d0 <x-coredata:///Article/t8BA04531-EB12-479D-9C0E-FF22ADE34A62201> ; data: {
    category = “0x7aeecc30 <x-coredata://5095458E-7D52-4717-A948-E58E1C13176D/Category/p27>“;
    categoryID = 5;
    content =     (
        “0x7c457250 <x-coredata:///Content/t8BA04531-EB12-479D-9C0E-FF22ADE34A62202>“,
        “0x7c18b890 <x-coredata:///Content/t8BA04531-EB12-479D-9C0E-FF22ADE34A62203>“,
        “0x7c454840 <x-coredata:///Content/t8BA04531-EB12-479D-9C0E-FF22ADE34A62204>”
    );
    featuredImage = “600x600(19).jpg”;
    id = 1;
    issueID = 1;
    mainImage = “1.jpg”;
    state = downloaded;
    title = “New Title”;
    version = “1.0”;
}), NSAffectedObjectsErrorKey=(
    “<Test.Content: 0x7c454880> (entity: Content; id: 0x7c454840 <x-coredata:///Content/t8BA04531-EB12-479D-9C0E-FF22ADE34A62204> ; data: {\n    article = nil;\n    content = \“<p>New Content For Testing</p>\“;\n    imageID = nil;\n    ordering = 3;\n    typeID = Paragraphs;\n})”
), NSValidationErrorKey=content, NSValidationErrorValue=Relationship ‘content’ on managed object (0x7c191030) <Test.Article: 0x7c191030> (entity: Article; id: 0x7c1927d0 <x-coredata:///Article/t8BA04531-EB12-479D-9C0E-FF22ADE34A62201> ; data: {
    category = “0x7aeecc30 <x-coredata://5095458E-7D52-4717-A948-E58E1C13176D/Category/p27>“;
    categoryID = 5;
    content =     (
        “0x7c457250 <x-coredata:///Content/t8BA04531-EB12-479D-9C0E-FF22ADE34A62202>“,
        “0x7c18b890 <x-coredata:///Content/t8BA04531-EB12-479D-9C0E-FF22ADE34A62203>“,
        “0x7c454840 <x-coredata:///Content/t8BA04531-EB12-479D-9C0E-FF22ADE34A62204>”
    );
    featuredImage = “600x600(19).jpg”;
    id = 1;
    issueID = 1;
    mainImage = “1.jpg”;
    state = downloaded;
    title = “New Title”;
    version = “1.0”;
}) with objects {(
    <Test.Content: 0x7c459270> (entity: Content; id: 0x7c457250 <x-coredata:///Content/t8BA04531-EB12-479D-9C0E-FF22ADE34A62202> ; data: {
    article = nil;
    content = “<p>Another Content with &lt;p&gt; Tag</p>“;
    imageID = nil;
    ordering = 1;
    typeID = Introduction;
}),
    <Test.Content: 0x7c190cf0> (entity: Content; id: 0x7c18b890 <x-coredata:///Content/t8BA04531-EB12-479D-9C0E-FF22ADE34A62203> ; data: {
    article = nil;
    content = “Last Content”;
    imageID = nil;
    ordering = 2;
    typeID = Illustration;
}),
    <Test.Content: 0x7c454880> (entity: Content; id: 0x7c454840 <x-coredata:///Content/t8BA04531-EB12-479D-9C0E-FF22ADE34A62204> ; data: {
    article = nil;
    content = “<p>New Content For Testing</p>“;
    imageID = nil;
    ordering = 3;
    typeID = Paragraphs;
})
)}, NSValidationErrorShouldAttemptRecoveryKey=true}: file /Users/user/Documents/Development/Test/Test/Issues/IssuesViewController.swift, line 322
```

I believe It's due to concurrency but also am unsure about the relationships
Here are the article and content models

[image]
[image]

and here's the main API. Am I using the perform block correctly ? should I use it? Am I overusing it ?

```
func getArticleDetailsForArticleId(whereArticleId articleId: String, andCategoryObj categoryObj: Category)
    {
        //let issue = (Array(categoryObj.issue!) as! [Issue])[0]
        let group = /*issue.articleDispatchGroup*/categoryObj.issue!.articleDispatchGroup
        let queue = /*issue.articleQueue*/categoryObj.issue!.articleQueue
        var errors = /*issue.articleErrors*/categoryObj.issue!.articleErrors

        group.enter()
        let privateMOC = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
        privateMOC.parent =  (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

        group.enter()
        privateMOC.perform {

        categoryObj.state = State.downloading.rawValue
        do {
            try privateMOC.save()
            privateMOC.parent!.perform {
                do {
                    try privateMOC.parent!.save()
                } catch {
                    fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
                }
            }
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
        }
        }

        print("saved category is downloading")
        DataManager.sharedInstance.getArticleDetails(whereArticleId: articleId, andCompletionHandler:  { (success, response) in

            let privateMOC = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
            privateMOC.parent =  (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
            print("I am articleId \(articleId)")
            // SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
            //self.apiInProgress = false
            if success
            {
                privateMOC.perform/* queue.async*/{

                let articleDetail = response.responseData as! Article
                articleDetail.state = State.downloaded.rawValue

                //queue.async {

                //categoryObj.addToArticles(articleDetail)
                //categoryObj.


                     //categoryObj.addToArticles(articleDetail)
                    let articles = NSMutableOrderedSet(orderedSet: categoryObj.articles!)
                    for content in Array(articleDetail.content!)
                    {
                        (content as! Content).article = articleDetail // should I add this line or the inverse relatioship is enough to set this
                        //privateMOC.parent?.insert(content as! Content)
                    }
                   // privateMOC.parent?.insert(articleDetail)

                    //articleDetail.content = NSOrderedSet(array: articleDetail.contents!)
                    articles.add(articleDetail)
                     categoryObj.articles = articles

                    //articleDetail.category = categoryObj
                    //categoryObj.theArticles.append(articleDetail)

                    categoryObj.issue!.articlesDownloaded += 1//categoryObj.issue?.articlesDownloaded += 1
                    let progress = CGFloat(categoryObj.issue!.articlesDownloaded)/CGFloat(categoryObj.issue!.articlesCount)
                    OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                        self.issuesToProgressDictionary[categoryObj.issue!]?.pathFromProgress(whereProgress: progress,andFillColor: UIColor(red: 64/1255.0, green: 121/255.0, blue: 117/255.0, alpha: 0.4),andStrokeColor: UIColor.clear)
                        categoryObj.state = State.downloaded.rawValue

                        //(UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()
                    })
                    do {
                        try privateMOC.save()
                        privateMOC.parent!.perform {
                            do {
                                try privateMOC.parent!.save()
                            } catch {
                                let categoryObjec = categoryObj
                                let articDet = articleDetail
                                fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
                            }
                        }
                    } catch {
                        fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
                    }  
                } 
            }  
    else
    {
    queue.async {
    errors.append(response.responseError!.errorMessage!)
    }
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "OOPS", message: response.responseError?.errorMessage, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Try Again", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
    self.getIssues()
    }))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    group.leave()
})

}
```

Here's a sample NSManagedObject : Article

```
//
//  Article+CoreDataClass.swift
//
//
//  Created by User on 7/12/17.
//
//

import Foundation
import CoreData
import ObjectMapper

//@objc(Article)
public class Article: NSManagedObject, Mappable {

    var contents : [Content]?
    //var content: NSOrderedSet?
    required public init?(map: Map) {
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Article", in: context)

        super.init(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)
        self.mapping(map: map)
        self.content = NSOrderedSet(array: self.contents!)
          }
        //        }

    }

    override init(entity: NSEntityDescription, insertInto context: NSManagedObjectContext?) {
        super.init(entity: entity, insertInto: (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext)
    }


    //private override init(){}

    public func mapping(map: Map)
    {

        featuredImage <- map["FeaturedImage"]
        issueID <- map["IssueID"]
        mainImage <- map["MainImage"]
        title <- map["Title"]
        version <- map["Version"]
        categoryID <- map["categoryID"]
        id <- map["ArticleID"]
        contents <- map["Content"]
        //content =  NSOrderedSet(array: map["Content"] as! [Content])
        state = State.nothing.rawValue
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at line:

```
  DataManager.sharedInstance.getArticleDetails(whereArticleId: articleId, andCompletionHandler:  { (success, response) in
```

Here you request CoreData models from one thread and process them into other thread:

```
privateMOC.perform/* queue.async*/{

 let articleDetail = response.responseData as! Article
 articleDetail.state = State.downloaded.rawValue
 <....>
```

You shouldn't share CoreData models between [threads](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html).

> NSManagedObject instances are not intended to be passed between
>   queues. Doing so can result in corruption of the data and termination
>   of the application. When it is necessary to hand off a managed object
>   reference from one queue to another, it must be done through
>   NSManagedObjectID instances.

Comment: I tried adding this

 let categoryObj = privateMOC.parent!.object(with: categoryObj.objectID) as! Category - just inside DataManager.sharedInstance.getArticleDetails {} //It made no difference

Comment: Are you sure that "categoryObj.objectID" from current thread? I think that the complitionHandler of method getArticleDetails is called on the main thread, but request executes on background thread. If it is not so, may be I'm wrong.

Comment: I think you should return to complitionHandler the a array of UIDs (not a array of objects) from getArticleDetails method.

Comment: getArticleDetails is an API call so in the completionHandler am getting back the success {true or false} and response {json mapped into article object}

Answer (score 0):

As has already been explained, the main problem is that you are passing objects from one context to another context.  You appear to have many methods that make assumption about what context to use instead of the context being passed as a parameter.

For example:

```
 override init(entity: NSEntityDescription, insertInto context: NSManagedObjectContext?) {
    super.init(entity: entity, insertInto: (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext)
}
```

You are assuming that all object creation will take place on the main context.  Any attempt to create an object with a different context will crash.  It appears that you are trying to make object creation simpler and more convenient by always getting the main context.  That is a mistake. You are making you code FAR more complex by not easily know what context you are using.

Likewise the method `DataManager.sharedInstance.getArticleDetails` appears to do a fetch and return the result in a block.  Which context does it use? what thread does it return on?  If it uses the main context then must it be run on the main thread or does it do a dispatch_async inside?  It is hard to know with the code that you have because the context of the fetch is hidden away.  Adding performBlock everywhere won't solve your problem if you can't keep track of what context you using.  Instead a method that does `getArticleDetails(whereArticleId:, inContext:)` is a lot easier to understand and use.

I don't understand most of your code. It appears to be a big mess. I looks like you started crashing so you added more performBlock and more threading without fixing any of the real issue.  The key point to understand is that for every core-data action - fetching, inserting, updating - you must know what the context is and must call it from the correct thread.  So if you have a method that does a fetch in core data you MUST pass it a context.  If you just assume that the context is the main context you will get messed up.

If you have a method that is passed a managedObject then it should only be using the context of the object it was pass and return.  Passing managedObjects around and then using different context is a recipe for disaster.

I suggest using `NSPersistentContainer`.  Do all your reading with the `viewContext` and do all you writing with `performBackgroundTask:`.  Don't use any objects that created in  `performBackgroundTask:` outside of the block.

Comment: I tried running things on main queue since I'm using the main context. Still it's crashing sometimes.

Comment: I wish I could help more, but I honestly can't understand your code.